# Json LocalDate Deserializer not being called

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

### LocalDateDeserializer not being called.

I decided to transfer my date objects to the front-end as Long miliseconds since epoch. I've written a Serializer to convert LocalDate Object to Long miliseconds since epoch and a deserializer to convert the long value gotten from the json back to a LocalDate.

On the Client side I create a JS Date Object from this value and convert the Date Object back to milliseconds since epoch when I want to send object back to the server.

### Serializer and Deserializer

```
public class LocalDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDate> {
@Override
public void serialize(LocalDate localDate, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    /*
        Converting LocalDate to milliSeconds since epoch to easily transfer date objects.
     */
    jsonGenerator.writeString(Long.toString((localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond())*1000));
}
```

}

```
public class LocalDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {
@Override
public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    //Parsing json to LocalDate.
    Long sinceEpoch = Long.parseLong(jsonParser.getValueAsString());
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(sinceEpoch).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
}
```

}

### ObjectMapper Configuration

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JSR310Module dateModule = new JSR310Module();
    dateModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
    dateModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
    SimpleModule valueTypeModule = new SimpleModule();
    valueTypeModule.addDeserializer(AbstractValueType.class, new ValueTypeDeserializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(dateModule);
    objectMapper.registerModule(valueTypeModule);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

### Problems

The Serializer is called The way it should, but the deserializer isn't. I'm getting this error:

```
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDate] from String value ('-30610224561000'); no single-String constructor/factory method
```

### Additional information

I'm not using JavaTimeModule because I'm using an older version of Jackson in order to keep compadibility with with other dependencies I have.

I'm trying to not use the annotations because the domain model is located in a separate maven module and trying to make as little changes to that as possible.

If there is any more information you might need, feel free to leave a comment!

Comment: We're facing the same issue. It only gets called if we add the @JsonDeserialize annotation explicitly.. which is rather disappointing.. :)